# WordPress Block Editor Gutenberg running code inside ! is_admin()

Tags: php, block-editor, conditional-tags

In my functions.php I have some code inside a function that has a if (! is_admin) condition around it.  For some reason the code inside this condition is running when I edit a page in the admin.  Its throwing an error which results in the page not saving.

Here is a sample of the code setup.

```
function conditional_payment_gateways($available_gateways){

    if (!is_admin()){

        $payment_type_ins = false;
        $payment_type_both = false;
        
        foreach (WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item){
            $payment_type = $cart_item['variation']['attribute_pa_payment-type'];
            $product_type = get_post_meta($cart_item['product_id'], 'type', true );
    
            if ($payment_type == 'pay-with-insurance' && $product_type != 'Both'){
                $payment_type_ins = true;
            }
    
            if ($product_type == 'Both'){
                $payment_type_both = true;
            }
        }
    
        if($payment_type_ins){
            unset($available_gateways['authorize_net_cim_credit_card']);
        } else if ($payment_type_ins == false && $payment_type_both == false){
            unset($available_gateways['cod']);
        }
    
        return $available_gateways;
    }
}

add_filter('woocommerce_available_payment_gateways', 'conditional_payment_gateways', 10, 1);
```

Here is the error it causes when it runs in the editor.

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function get_cart()
```

Is there a better way to do this?

**Edit:** Added the full code along with the error it causing when it runs in the editor

**Edit #2:**

OK, So I figured out a solution for my particular problem.

Instead of using **!is_admin()** I can use the **is_cart()** & **is_checkout()** conditionals.

```
function conditional_payment_gateways($available_gateways){

    if (is_cart() || is_checkout()){

        // Code here won't fire in the admin area
        
    }
}

add_filter('woocommerce_available_payment_gateways', 'conditional_payment_gateways', 10, 1);
```

But, I think the larger question still remains.  If **is_admin()** is no longer reliable in the block editor, what should we use?

As Pat J pointed out in a answer below, [this is supposed to be a work around](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/47394).  But it didn't work for me.

Comment: Why would it matter if code in the `woocommerce_available_payment_gateways` hook ran in the editor? That's a bit of a red flag. What code is running and what impact is it having?

Comment: I edited the question to include the full code along with the error is causes when it runs in the editor

Answer (score 0):

It appears [this is a known issue with the block editor (aka Gutenberg)](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/47394).

That Trac ticket suggests a workaround, too: replace your

```
if ( ! is_admin() ) { ... }
```

with something like this:

```
global $current_screen;
if ( 
    ( ! is_admin() ) && 
    ( ! 
        ( 
            // Checks the value of WP_Screen::is_block_editor().
            $current_screen instanceof \WP_Screen && 
            $current_screen->is_block_editor()
        )
    )
   ) { ... }
```

This code is **untested**. I'm pretty sure I matched the `(` and `)` but make sure it works as expected before you put it in production.

If you're doing this in a lot of locations (ie, > 1), I'd suggest creating a helper function even closer to the code suggested in the Trac ticket's comments:

```
function wpse416155_is_admin() {
    if ( is_admin() ) {
        return true;
    }
    global $current_screen;
    if ( $current_screen instanceof \WP_Screen &&
         $current_screen->is_block_editor() ) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

// ...
// ...
// ...

if ( ! wpse416155_is_admin() ) {
    // ...your non-admin code here...
}
```

Comment: Interesting.  I tested this and my code is still running in the editor.  I tried changing the priority on add_filter as a desperate attempt but it had no effect.

Comment: If I var_dump() $current_screen it returns like 4 times, the first is NULL and the rest have something like object(WP_Screen)#410 (18) { ... ["is_block_editor"]=> bool(true)}

Comment: Hmm. It's possible that the `woocommerce_available_payment_gateways` hook happens too early for `$current_screen` to be set (see [this comment in the Trac ticket](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/47394#comment:5)), in which case I don't know where you'd go next.

Comment: Yeah, I seen that comment, that's why I was hoping changing the priority would do something but it didn't.  Thanks for your time, I'll have to keep playing around

Comment: I guess as a workaround/ugly hack/Hail Mary you could check the current URL for the string `wp-admin` in the `wpse416155_is_admin()` function.

Comment: I might have to do that, at least for now until I can find a better solution